# Flutter Hive package initialisation error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I tried use [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) package in my application. But when I initialised in my app get error message:

> The following HiveError was thrown building MyApp(dirty): Box not
> found. Did you forget to call Hive.openBox()?

Her is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart' as path_provider;

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final appDocDir = await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(appDocDir.path);
  runApp(MyApp());
  final box = await Hive.openBox('storage');
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final box = Hive.box('storage');
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test App',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: CheckAuth(),
    );
  }
}

class CheckAuth extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CheckAuthState createState() => _CheckAuthState();
}

class _CheckAuthState extends State<CheckAuth> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text('Hive initialised!'),
    );
  }
}
```

**Emulator**

- API: 28
- Android: 9

**Packages**

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  hive: ^1.4.4+1
  hive_flutter: ^0.3.1
  http: ^0.12.2
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  path_provider: ^1.6.24

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  hive_generator: ^0.8.2
  build_runner: ^1.10.11

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Where I have any error in my code?

Comment: What if you add openBox call before runApp ?

Comment: yes i think you need to call it before runApp

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `await Hive.initFlutter()` instead of `Hive.init()`? The former is supposed to take care of proper app folder path on specific platform and put it's files there.

It is part of **package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart** which deals with Flutter specific stuff